# Disambiguate nested class and member function with same name in template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

See the example: [compilable here](https://cpp.sh/?source=%2F%2F%20Example%20program%0A%23include%20%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include%20%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename%20T%3E%20class%20Foo%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Nes%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20void%20Nes()%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint%20main()%0A%7B%0A%20%20std%3A%3Astring%20name%3B%0A%20%20cout%20%3C%3C%20typeid(%26Foo%3Cint%3E%3A%3ANes)%3B%0A%0A%7D)

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo {
    public:
    
    class Nes{};

    void Nes(){}

    using Ptr = void(Nes::*)();
 };

 template<typename T> class Bar
 {
 public:

     using Ptr = void(T::Nes::*)();
 };

int main()
{
    using F = void(Foo::Nes::*)();
    F compiles;

    Bar<Foo>::Ptr notCompiles;

    std::cout << typeid(Foo).name();
}
```

How can tell to the compiler that Nes should be the class and not the method?

Comment: Not sure if it helps in the template, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691821/nested-class-and-member-function-with-same-name

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, already checked. I tried to alias nested types using typedefs in template without luck. Current back plan in to rename Nes(), but I'd avoid it.

Comment: Did you try to remove the `&`?

Comment: @Daniel Do you mean the member function pointer reference? Shamelessly yes, at some point. The problem is that I cannot declare the member function pointer correctly.

Comment: I found this behavior on MSVC2015, and on the linked cpp.sh website (no idea what GCC they are using. GCC 5.4 and GCC 7.1 compiles without issues.

Comment: @jxn Look for Pointer to Member function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case:

```cpp
template<typename T> class Bar {
public:
    using Ptr = typename T::Ptr;
};
```

If `T` doesn't have a `Ptr` type definition:

```cpp
template <typename T> class Bar {
public:
    using TNes = class T::Nes;
    using Ptr = void (TNes::*)();
};
```

Comment: And after looking through the standard, I don't think there is any valid syntax to do it without `using TNes`.

Comment: @user17732522 I'm scratching my head myself :-) It seems very odd but I can't figure out any way to get around it.

Comment: I already tried. It makes sense... but: *error: typename specifier refers to non-type member 'Nes' in 'Foo'
  using TNes = typename T::Nes;* The actual problem is the member function Nes().

Comment: @Luca That was a temporary mistake in the answer. I had `class` then changed it to `typename` only to change it back to `class`.

Comment: Whoa. You made my day, sir. *class* keyword was the key!

Comment: @TedLyngmo The problem is that the nested name here is part of the declarator, i.e. https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#nt:ptr-operator, but that allows specifically _only_ for a nested-type-specifier, not an elaborated-name-specifier that you would want here. I couldn't find any discussion yet on why this choice was made. Maybe the choice was made because elaborated-type-specifiers are basically just a C compatibility feature. If it wasn't for that I think it wouldn't be allowed to define the same name as a type and non-type in the same scope.

Comment: @user17732522 That sounds like a very plausible explanation. Thanks for the digging!